# Sending large data from a server to another

Tags: php, curl, http-post

I am using CURL to send large amounts of data between servers , am using POST , is this OK or is there any better/standard way to send large serialized data with curl ?

the problem is in the max-post-size in the php settings , i have to change it (default 2MB) . i didn't encounter any problems with this yet , but when the system will be online it is possible that data larger than 50MB will be sent each time !

Any ideas ?
Thank you .

**EDIT :**

I am sending DATA and not FILES , a data that once received should be processed by the second server and saved to database/file/do some action and might need to send a response after processing the data .

I just would like to know , will i face any other problem except max-post-size ? (forget about timeouts of both curl and php) , and is there anyway to make the server not look at max_post_size ? maybe by using PUSH ? or PUT ? does that post_size affect the PUSH or PUT ?? and how to use it via curl ?
so many questions !

Comment: Well, if you can compress the data, that might reduce it and therefore it would be better. But apart from that, POST looks like the valid HTTP method to send the data. There is also PUT but it should be much similar.

Comment: I, personally, would use an AJAX-based method such as `jsonp` as opposed to CURL. Curl is exceedingly slow, while AJAX is virtually instant.

Comment: @Austin: I bet that's not the case here.

Comment: True, it depends on his goal and how he plans to use the data.

Comment: @Austin i am sending data between 2 servers , no browsers , no javascript to use ajax . and even json requires some sort of connection , so what would it be ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using cURL is perfectly fine.

Personally, I would prefer to not having to do it through web server (eg. Apache) as there can be too many potential faults along the way, eg. PHP timeout, web server timeout, memory limit, no write privileges, limited to web root, etc.

I would prefer to do it through mechanisms designed for file transfers:

- FTP
- `scp` (generally FTP over SSH)
- Dropbox (there are APIs)
- Amazon S3 (simple API with [PHP library](http://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-php.git))
- etc.

Comment: FTP would be slow , i am not sending FILES i am sending DATA which has to be processed , and for sure i won't use a 3rd party !!

Answer (score 0):

The way is ok.

Two more ideas for you:

1. Use FTP (you can upload large serialized files to a ftp-server which is reachable from your servers
2. Use mysql (you can store the large serialized content on a mysql-server)

Comment: I would advise against using MySQL. It's not really designed for transporting files (esp. large ones).

Comment: FTP would be slow , because i am sending DATA to be processed and not files ! .